# How do you save a join as a Snowflake table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand how a Join is made in Snowflake but I need to temporarily save it as a table, how can it be possible make it using consola?

(For this project I can't do it with any connectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [CREATE TABLE AS SELECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html) or CTAS pattern:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table AS 
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM VALUES ('a'),('b')) a(string)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM VALUES (1),(2)) b(vals); 

SELECT * FROM tmp_table;
```

gives:

| STRING | VALS |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 2 |

and if you want it to be temporary for the session you might want to add TEMP

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table AS
```